# How to pass props through a Link component or an useNavigate() hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to pass `token` and `setToken` props from **App.jsx** into **Books.jsx** and from **Books.jsx** into **Login.jsx**.

**App.jsx**

```
function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  return (
     <>
       <Books token={token} setToken={setToken}></Books> 
     </>
  );
}
```

**Books.jsx**

How would you pass the `token` and `setToken` props into the Link component or useNavigate() hook so that the Login component has access to it?

```
function Books({token,setToken}) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
     <>
       <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
       <button onClick={()=>navigate('/login')}>Login</button>
     </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where do you render the `<Login>` component? You will either need to pass a prop to it there, or you will need to use router state.

Comment: Note also that you can only pass JSON serializable data through route state. Trying to pass the `setToken` function will actually nullify the entire passed state object. If you need to expose state and functions to descendent components you may want to consider using a [React Context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) instead.